# Cannot install PyFlux for python 3.7

Tags: python, anaconda

When I try installing PyFlux for Python 3.7, I get errors. When `pip install pyflux`, I get a long error message stating "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:...". When using `conda install pyflux`, I get another error:

> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment:
>   failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current channels:
>
> - pyflux
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
>   you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: `pip3 install pyflux` <-- Try `pip3` for Python3.x

Comment: _When `pip install pyflux`, I get a long error message_ Please provide the entire error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same issue

This GitHub Installation [issue](https://github.com/RJT1990/pyflux/issues/102) and its [solution](https://github.com/RJT1990/pyflux/issues/102#issuecomment-321729570) worked for me

You need to download a pyflux wheel file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyflux) related to the python version in use.
Put the wheel file in the current working directory and try pip install [wheel file name]:

```
!pip install pyflux-0.4.17-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

above mentioned is the wheel file that worked for my python version and desktop.

I hope that helps !

Comment: Perfect. Make sure you copy the file name to your notebook properly. Mine was !pip install pyflux-0.4.17-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/RJT1990/pyflux
```

Comment: awesome thank you worked on google colab